# Error while trying to import .sql file in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

[image]I'm trying to import an sql file of size 3.2GB. So definitely I would need to do it using cmdsql.
But the problem is that the server I'm trying to connect with in SSMS has no password and that is giving me the error.
I'm usig the following command in cmd:

sqlcmd -S DESKTOP-7QKBPG7\SQLEXPRESS -d XVMS-4.6 -U CSNA\kamran.bajwa -P -i C:\Users\kamran.bajwa\Downloads\XVMS\SCHEMA-DATA-16-06-2022\SCHEMA-DATA.sql -o C:\Users\kamran.bajwa\Downloads\XVMS\SCHEMA-DATA-16-06-2022\logs.txt

As of the"-P" there is no password so if I use an empty string "" then it gives me the following error in the log file:

Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'CSNA\kamran.bajwa'..

Comment: You don't import a SQL script, you execute it. The error has nothing to do with the script though, it says the credentials are wrong. `As of the"-P" there is no password` I *seriously* doubt this. You can't have any account without a password, except for some special purpose system accounts.

Comment: Please see the question again, now I have attached the image too.

Comment: Are you trying to use a Windows account perhaps? Windows authentication means the script will be executed using *your* account. Windows already knows your account so there's no need for either a username or password. You can't specify another Windows account. Use `-E` instead of `-U` and `-P`

Comment: And the .sql file size is 3.2GB then how can I import it into SSMS?

Comment: That's Windows authentication. Accounts and passwords aren't used. Use `-E` instead

Comment: Again, you import nothing. Scripts aren't data. You execute them, you don't import them. SSMS is just another client tool, the same as sqlcmd as far as SQL Server is concerned

Comment: You mean like this?

sqlcmd -S DESKTOP-7QKBPG7\SQLEXPRESS -d XVMS-4.6 -E -i C:\Users\kamran.bajwa\Downloads\XVMS\SCHEMA-DATA-16-06-2022\SCHEMA-DATA.sql -o C:\Users\kamran.bajwa\Downloads\XVMS\SCHEMA-DATA-16-06-2022\logs.txt

Comment: Why are you trying to move data using scripts anyway? That's an extremely inefficient way. Almost half of the text is waste in `INSERT` clauses. What are you actually trying to do? Migrate a database? Copy data from one system to another? Take a backup using MySQL tricks? You could take a real database backup and even compress it, then restore it on the other server. MySQL allows you to take real backups too, but only if you have the Enterprise edition

Comment: The sql fil;e I'm trying to import is of 3.2gb, that's why I'm using scripts

Comment: I'm still getting the following error:

Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'CSNA\kamran.bajwa'..
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Cannot open database "XVMS-4.6" requested by the login. The login failed..

Comment: Does that database exist? Do you have permission to connect to it? Do you really have a database with a dot in its name?